# Need help figuring out what this symbol means

Tags: identification

[image]

I can't find what this symbol means. Any of you guys know? It was on the schematic of an old tractor next to the ignition coil.[image]

Comment: It's difficult to know just from that, can you add more of the schematic?

Comment: i added the whole schmatic.

Comment: It could be a bullet connector.

Comment: I see there are letters "A,B,C..." etc. One of the letters, though, I can't tell from here because it's possible that the lighting is inconsistent with the picture you took, is pointing towards the component. What does the schematic say about that letter that is pointing to the component? I'm talking about the bottom in the center of the picture you provided below "E1 Spark Plug".

Comment: This looks like a male/female connector symbol

Comment: Could be a fuseable link. edit: Or not.

Comment: @Steve I doubt they would put three fuses in series.  Honestly, as poor as CrispFilament's answer is, I think it is right.

Comment: thank you all for the feedback, Steve might be right about the bullet connector, it make sense. the schematic is not complete and the information i got for the letters are not useful at all.

Comment: @Test  Have you got access to the actual tractor?  Can you post the picture of the board or cable harness that this schematic is for?

Comment: i don't have access to the tractor myself. It is for a co worker.

Comment: Above or below?  The ones below the ignition coils have to be the switched that chops up the current and allows the coils to function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the obvious answer is to take the schematic to the tractor and figure it out. If the parts in question are no longer with the tractor, that will make it difficult.

The likely hood of getting the right answer with your current approach is low. The symbol for Fusible Link is clearly labeled on the left middle and doesn't look like the one in question, so it's probably not a fusible link. If we could see the key which describes what each letter/symbol means it would help eliminate some things.

I don't often see connectors represented in wiring diagrams in my experience, though I can't recall ever looking at a tractor wiring diagram.